# Derivative of a function with respect to x containing integral over y

Tags: integration, derivatives

does anyone know how to take a derivative of a function with respect to a variable if that function contains an integral over another variable? For example, what would be the derivative of the following function with respect to x?
$$f = \int (2x^2y)dy$$
I think it would be 
$$f’(x) =\int (4xy)dy$$
but I haven’t found any rule according which it should be so... just used intuition.

Any formal explanation or link to such would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See Titchmarch: Theory of functions: derivative under integral sign, first or second chapter.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: In this example, if x is independent of y then you can take it out of the integral sign and differentiate it as you normally would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you surmised is in fact true, because inside the integral, $x$ is just some constant, so for any $a,b$
$$\int_{y=a}^b (2x^2 y) dy =2x^2 \int_{y=a}^b y\, dy $$ and you merely differentiated that (the constant now is the integral) with respect to $x$.

A closely related but less trivial technique is called
 "differentiation under the integral sign."  This says that 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left[ \int_{y=a}^b f(x,y) dy \right] = \int_{y=a}^b \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} dy$$
That holds for all $f(x,y)$ that are sufficiently well behaved (certainly holds it it has a continuous derivative, it may hold even with weaker constraints).

Comment: Thank you, studied that a little... but what if the integral is not definite? Would that rule be applicable as well?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).